# Subtracting one row variable from another in Postgres cursor

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL PostgreSQL 13.9 with PostGIS 3.1 extension to calculate vectors between a sample of points from a larger table.

The function works fine if I specify the individual field names using dot notation in the example below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_vectors() RETURNS void
AS $$
DECLARE points CURSOR FOR SELECT st_x(geom) as x, st_y(geom) as y, st_z(geom) as z FROM test_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 3;  
    p1 test_vectors%ROWTYPE;
    p3 test_vectors%ROWTYPE; 
    v1 test_vectors%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN 
OPEN points; 
FETCH FIRST FROM points INTO p1; 
FETCH NEXT FROM points INTO p3;
v1.x := p3.x - p1.x;
DELETE FROM test_vectors;
INSERT INTO test_vectors VALUES (v1.*);
CLOSE points; 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT get_vectors();

SELECT * FROM test_vectors ;
```

The `test_vectors` table looks like:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.0940000000409782 | [null] | [null] |

However if I replace the subtraction with `v1 := p3 - p1;` to operate at the row level, I get an error saying `ERROR:  operator does not exist: test_vectors - test_vectors`.

What is confusing me is that when using window function like LEAD or LAG, subtraction of one row is allowed (e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300023/postgresql-subtract-to-each-row-the-previous-row).
Why doesn't this work inside a function with a declared ROWTYPE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you linked `lag()` and `lead()` get a specific `numeric`-type field from another row, not the entire other row. That's what enables the subtraction directly on the output of those. In the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE), you can see that selecting the `value` you want to get from the other row is not optional (unlike the stuff square brackets):

> `lead ( value anycompatible [, offset integer [, default anycompatible ]] ) → anycompatible`
>
> Returns value evaluated at the row that is *offset* rows after the current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead returns *default* (which must be of a type compatible with *value*). Both *offset* and *default* are evaluated with respect to the current row. If omitted, *offset* defaults to 1 and *default* to `NULL`.

In that case, value retrieved from the other row is of a built-in numeric type known to PostgreSQL and it has a built-in function that defines how to handle subtraction for that type.

In your case, the `test_vectors` is your own, custom, user-defined table, so there's no way for PostgreSQL to know what it would mean to subtract its whole rows, unless you define a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) accepting records of this table, then a subtraction [operator `-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html) that applies that function to its left and right argument when it detects they are both of `test_vectors` type.

You can also start with defining a [custom type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) then `create table your_table of your_custom_type;` and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek, I had overlooked that the column name is specified in the examples to give a value. Now it's clear.